# Expression returning incorrect answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is an expression in a SQL query which is returning a wrong answer, but when I write the same query on calculator, it returns the same result.

Suppose value of (batch.received_percentage) is equal to 10, then calculator returns 220.35, but SQL Server returns 259.245.

```
((invoice.unit_price * (1 - (15) / 100))*
((1 - (batch.received_percentage) / 100)))
```

Comment: what was the value of invoice.unit_price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  You can probably fix this by changing these subexpressions:

```
(invoice.unit_price * (1 - (15) / 100.0))
```

and:

```
(1 - (batch.received_percentage) / 100.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical calculations always follow BODMAS rule:

- B-Brackets
- O-open
- D-division
- M-multiplication
- A-addition
- S-subtraction

> ((invoice.untiprice)*((1-15)/100)*(1-((batch.received_percentage)/100))

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your expression a little bit:

```
invoice.unit_price * (100-batch.received_percentage) * 0.0085
```